# Can I `fn.apply` with `arguments` or do I've to convert `arguments` to Array first?

Tags: javascript, arrays, arguments

I'm learning about `.apply` and `arguments` and I've a question - Can I `fn.apply` with `arguments` or do I've to convert `arguments` to Array first?

This code example that I created suggests that I can just `apply` with `arguments`:

```
function aaa () {
    bbb.apply(undefined, arguments)
}

function bbb () {
    console.dir(arguments)
}

aaa(1,2,3,4) // calls bbb and bbb's arguments are 1, 2, 3, 4
```

I can also convert arguments to Array, and it also works:

```
function aaa () {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    bbb.apply(undefined, args)
}

function bbb () {
    console.dir(arguments)
}

aaa(1,2,3,4) // calls bbb and bbb's arguments are 1, 2, 3, 4
```

Should I use one or the other, is there any difference at all?

Comment: There is no need to convert it to an array, you can use `arguments` directly

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to transform `arguments` into an array.  [Any array-like argument will do](http://es5.github.io/#x15.3.4.3):

```
var args = {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, length: 3}
// Note that this is an object, not an array

function test() { console.log(arguments); }

test.apply(undefined, args);
// Logs [1, 2, 3]
```

However, there are reasons to pass `arguments` on directly rather turning it into an array before passing it to `apply`.  For example, passing `arguments` directly is optimized for in some browsers (I know for example, [that it is optimized in Chrome](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Optimization-killers#what-is-safe-arguments-usage)).